# qTip2 inside iframe detect mouseenter & mousemove

Tags: jquery, iframe, qtip2

I have a dynamically loaded iframe. I want the qtips to show when the user hover over certain elements and the qtips will follow the cursor once inside the element. I can't use the option `target: 'mouse'` because qtips inside iframe are fixed positioned to the parent container. I got something that kinda work except the tips are still displaced from my cursor, only in the y axis, where in FF the distance is furthest and IE being the closest. I know this is not the right way to implement it, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
$("#pageFrame").load(function() {
    var pageFrameContent  = $(this).contents()[0];
    $("div.extra", pageFrameContent)
    .mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).mousemove(function(e){
        $(this).qtip({
                position: {
                    target: [e.screenX,e.screenY]
                },
                show: {
                    solo: true,
                    ready: true,
                    delay: 0
                },
                hide:{
                    event: 'click mouseleave'               
                },
                content: 'Tips content',
                style: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: I managed to fix the displaced issue by using `target: [e.clientX,e.clientY]` but still i wonder detecting if mouseenter & mousemove will affect the performance...

Answer (score 1):

Craig answered this question on the [qTip2 forum](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-qtip-in-iframe-and-mouse-tracking). Turns out it's the best if you can create the tips within the iframe.